# Return 0 instead of count based on condition

Tags: sql

I need this query to return 0 when there are no **status='Completed'** for those EmpID who doesn't have any Completed status

```
select  EmployeeID, count(Status)
from tbl1
group by EmployeeID
where Status = 'Completed';
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what db is this?

Comment: try something with CASE

Comment: `IF EXISTS() ... ELSE`

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using. (You've already got product specific suggestion.)

Comment: @RajDhanani Can you please write the script with CASE I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: Self join to tbl1 so all records are retuned and get the count from the second table coalesce the results so 0 is provided when otherwise would be null

Comment: Do you mean _any_ EmployeeID, or _an_ EmployeeID?

Comment: Much better, now I understand what you want!

Comment: 1) Skip the WHERE clause. 2) Use a case expression inside the count().

Comment: Instead of eliminating rows (and many employees) before you have a chance to count them, you want to simply count the ones that are relevant to the results. `count(case when status = 'Completed' then 1 else null end` You could also use a `sum()` if that makes more sense to you.

Comment: maybe just create a stored procedure and use that if conditionals are too complicated

Answer (score 1):

The issue is if an employee doesn't have a completed status they get excluded from the results.  You need to get a count that includes them so

1. get dataset for a distinct list of employees
2. get datset for the counts with the imposed limits
3. Coalesce the 0 when there are no counts matching the imposed limits.

.

```
SELECT A.EmployeeID, coalesce(B.Count,0)
FROM (SELECT Distinct EmployeeID FROM tbl1) A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmployeeID, count(Status) 
           FROM tbl1 
           WHERE status = 'Completed'
           GROUP BY Employee ID)
 on A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
```

Alternatively: don't eliminate them

```
SELECT EmployeeID, sum(case when status = 'completed' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

pro's cons either way depending on indexes and data volumes.